# Multiple Timer continue(running on background) even the page/browser is closed or refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, timer, setinterval

I'm new to HTML and JavaScript. I couldn't find any solution for preventing the timers on page restart itself when the page closed or refresh.

I want the timer will continue running even I close the page/browser.

Eg: If the timer count down for 1 Hour, I activated it and closed it. After 30 min, I reopen the page, the remaining time should be 30min.

Here my timer code:

```js
function countdown(element, hours, minutes, seconds, oritime) {
  var interval;
  var htemp = 0;
  var mtemp = 0;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var el = document.getElementById(element);
    if (seconds == 0) {
      if (minutes == 0) {
        if (hours == 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          el.innerHTML = oritime;
          return;
        } else {
          if (htemp == 0) {
            minutes = 0;
            seconds = 0;
            htemp = 1;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (mtemp == 0) {
          seconds = 0;
          mtemp = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    if (hours > 0) {
      var hour_text = hours > 9 ? '' : '0';
    } else {
      var hour_text = '0';
    }
    if (minutes > 0) {
      var minute_text = minutes > 9 ? '' : '0';
    } else {
      var minute_text = '0';
    }
    var second_text = seconds > 9 ? '' : '0';
    el.innerHTML = hour_text + hours + ' : ' + minute_text + minutes + ' : ' + second_text + seconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
      if (minutes == 0) {
        if (hours == 0) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          el.innerHTML = oritime;
          return;
        } else {
          if (htemp == 1) {
            hours--;
            minutes = 59;
            seconds = 60;
            htemp = 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (mtemp == 1) {
          minutes--;
          seconds = 60;
          mtemp = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    seconds--;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('timer1',0,5,0,'5');" value="Start Timer 1">
<div id='timer1' color='red'>5</div>
<input type="button" onclick="countdown('timer2',0,5,0,'5');" value="Start Timer 2">
<div id='timer2' color='red'>5</div>
```

Will using cookies make it possible to solve this issue? If so, how?

I didn't use PHP or AJAX or jQuery as I have not learnt that yet. I don't have a server to publish the HTML file so I just found a solution which is publish using google drive.

Side topic, if there is any "free" server for people to upload HTML so that others can access via online, that would be great.

Comment: "for preventing the timers on page" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: I can see that you attempted clearInterval but if it's not working for you, it's because the variables have different scopes even though they are all called "interval". Use document.interval in place of interval and remove the "var" in front of it. document.interval isn't "a thing" but you can attach any variables to a DOM object. Try if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english.. I want the timer will continue running even I close the page/browser..
Eg: If the timer count down for 1 Hour, when I activated it and close it.. after 30 min, I reopen the page, the remaining time should be 30min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no. `Javascript` will run only while your browser is open and should not be used to save any data.

If you want a timer you should use a server and a server side language like `PHP` to do it.

EDIT:
Having said that, i found a `Jquery` [plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) that could be of use to you.

Comment: Not really true. You can use cookie to store values, and recalculate the timer when the visitor come back. But that's will not be really secure, because value can be changed by the user

Comment: Not only they can be changed by the user, they could also have been deleted etc... Not to mention it won't work with a different browser.

Comment: If using a cookie, can you show me example about how to store the timer and update it (not pause) when I reopen the page? I visited the w3schools.com but the example is not suitable for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to refactor your code a bit, such as:

```
if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0) {
// your else logic here...
}
```

You can also choose to use `switch` if you happen to use a lot of "nested ifs" and short-circuit logic.

And yes, as you move on into the world of javascript, you would find out a lot of interesting libraries and frameworks (basically with a lot of abstracted functions/ methods that a lot of smart brilliant people have pre-written for you) you can use to help you develop functions much faster!

Since you have only stored your element into a "variable", your timer would only run as long as the local session is live (i.e. all stored variables would be cleared once you close your browser/session).

If you want to play more with data storage and actual persistence data within a database, you should develop at least in a "local host" environment, which you can setup easily using "Nodejs" by downloading at https://nodejs.org/

Hope this helps your path of coding development!

Comment: Is there any reason you put `if (seconds && minutes && hours === 0) {` and not `if (seconds === 0 && minutes === 0 && hours === 0) {` ?

Comment: Hey thanks there for the reminder, forgot that the "&&" operator has a short-circuiting nature, have made the edits to my answer~